# WSO2 ESB Using user-data in other application

Tags: passwords, wso2, esb, salt

I'm working at an projekt with the wso2 esb.
For another application I would like to use the users from the wso2 esb database.
Is this possible? Because I think they use a salt for the sha256 password hash. Is there a way to use the data for authentification in another application without using the WSO2 IS?

---

I tried to use this for authentification:
http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.de/2013/02/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html

I copied the class LoginAdminServiceClient like in the blog. 
For getting an object of this class i used the following code:

```
package wso2conn;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.LoginAuthenticationExceptionException;

public class WSO2Conn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AxisFault {
        String authenticate = null;
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            LoginAdminServiceClient login = new LoginAdminServiceClient("https://localhost:9443");
            authenticate = login.authenticate("admin", "admin");
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WSO2Conn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (LoginAuthenticationExceptionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WSO2Conn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Session: " + authenticate);
    }
}
```

Imported Libraries:

- org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy_4.0.2.jar
- org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub_4.0.0.jar
- axis2_1.6.1.wso2v7.jar
- axis2-json_1.6.1.wso2v7.jar
- axis2-transport-jms_1.1.0.wso2v7.jar
- org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.stub_4.0.0.jar

If I'm running this project I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMFactory
    at wso2conn.LoginAdminServiceClient.<init>(LoginAdminServiceClient.java:18)
    at wso2conn.WSO2Conn.main(WSO2Conn.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 2 more
Java Result: 1
```

Maybe there are some Libraries missing or the backEndUrl is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AuthenticationAdminStub libraries for this purpose.

{..

authenticationAdminStub.login(userName, password, "localhost")

...
}

As explain in below blog.Though below blog explain how to use admin services, you can use logic part for your reference.

http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2013/02/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html

Comment: This description is really bad. I tried it and will add the code to my question. It's not working because I get an error.

Comment: This blog explains what maven dependency to put.